# Trying to save last searched class in android

Tags: android

I am working on a Question answer based app. I have ten levels or activities in my app. I want that if user click from main activity for new game.Then if he leave from 3rd level say then he must comeback on 3rd level by using continuous button from main Screen. I'm new here Can any body please share the code snippet please
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try for using sqllite in Your App.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [sharedpreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

To edit data from sharedpreference

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putInt("level", 3);
 editor.apply();
```

To retrieve data from shared preference

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.xxxx);

SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
int restoredLevel = prefs.getInt("level", -1);

if (restoredLevel >-1) {   /* continue game*/  }

}
```

Comment: Sir can I work on this problem using button i.e clickListener ?

Comment: Yes You can. When button clicked retrieve data (level) from shared preference and start game from last level.

Comment: how to manage this line for 10 levels
editor.putInt("level", 3);

Comment: When user answer question, save current level.
editor.putInt("level", level);

Comment: what if I do

editor.putInt("level", Level1);editor.putInt("level", Level2);editor.putInt("level", Level2);editor.putInt("level", Level3);editor.putInt("level", Level4);editor.putInt("level", Level5);editor.putInt("level", Level6);editor.putInt("level", Level7);editor.putInt("level", Level8);

Comment: All levels are my classes

Comment: Hasanaga sir how can i start last level. I never stored last level. if store then where tell me

Answer (score 0):

One possible way of doing this is you can save level no. in **SharedPreferences** (or in a file if you decide to store more than just one or few values) and based on the saved value on next launch, you can start your desired activity.

Comment: Sir can I work on this problem using button i.e clickListener ?

Comment: Yes, you can. When ever your clicklistener fires, you can decide which activity to open after fetching the value from SharedPreferences.

Comment: Sir can you share the code ?
I really do not know about shared pref   I have ten Levels